# Check if WebSocket Server is running (on localhost)

Tags: javascript, websocket

When I try to initialize a websocket connection to the server running on localhost with

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8025/myContextRoot");
```

in javascript, but the server hasn't completed starting up yet, I get the error

> SCRIPT12029: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12029, A connection with the server could not be established

How can I prevent this? I.e. how do I check if the server has already started or how can I force the WebSocket client to wait for the server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about:

```js
var webSocketFactory = {
  connectionTries: 3,
  connect: function(url) {
    var ws = new WebSocket(url);
    ws.addEventListener("error", e => {
      // readyState === 3 is CLOSED
      if (e.target.readyState === 3) {
        this.connectionTries--;

        if (this.connectionTries > 0) {
          setTimeout(() => this.connect(url), 5000);
        } else {
          throw new Error("Maximum number of connection trials has been reached");
        }

      }
    });
  }
};

var webSocket = webSocketFactory.connect("ws://localhost:8025/myContextRoot");
```

When you get a connection error, you can do a limited number of trial-errors to try to re-connect. Or you can endlessly try to reach the server.

Comment: Nice. Just a quick reminder, you don't need to do like `self = this` thingy since you already use arrows in the callbacks.

Comment: @Redu fixed ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is perfectly fine. I just would like to extend it a little bit further with promises.

```
var wsFactory = { tryCount: 3,
                  connect : function(url){
                              var ctx = this,
                                  ws  = new WebSocket(url);

                              return new Promise(function(v,x){
                                                   ws.onerror   = e => { console.log(`WS connection attempt ${4-ctx.tryCount} -> Unsuccessful`);
                                                                         e.target.readyState === 3 && --ctx.tryCount;
                                                                         if (ctx.tryCount > 0) setTimeout(() => v(ctx.connect(url)), 1000);
                                                                         else x(new Error("3 unsuccessfull connection attempts"));
                                                                       };
                                                   ws.onopen    = e => { console.log(`WS connection Status: ${e.target.readyState}`);
                                                                         v(ws);
                                                                       };
                                                   ws.onmessage = m => console.log(m.data);
                                                 });
                            }
                };

wsFactory.connect("ws://localhost:8025/myContextRoot")
         .then(ws => ws.send("Hey..! This is my first socket message"))
         .catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent (or put on hold) the WebSocket from starting / establish a connection. WebSocket automatically establishes a connection with the server when its declared. What you can do is place all your code inside `onopen` event handler that you want to execute on successful connection. So it would be like...

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8025/myContextRoot");
webSocket.onopen = function() {
  // code you want to execute
};
```

check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) article to know more about WebSocket.

Comment: And how about checking if the websocket server is already running before I execute ``var webSocket = new WebSocket()``? Would that be possible?

Comment: it doesn't matter whether the server is running or not (in the back-end). client will be connected (or attempt to connect) to the server when you first declare `var webSocket = new WebSocket()`

Answer (score 1):

Hence the protocol can't get queried by the server if it is not started, the only option is trial and error.

Or you could let the WebSocket server create a simple textfile with the timestamp of the startup in your web space directory where the javascript can retrieve it and than try to establish a connection. You can retrieve the textfile with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).